# Javascript is not functioning properly, please have a quick look to debug

Tags: php, javascript, printing, formatting

I have a bit of Javascript which exists in a PHP script.  Here it is:

```
// start of JS script
print("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> <!--\n");
print("function storeData()");
print("{");
print("pos_index = ff_getElementByName('selectFormField').selectedIndex;"); 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) 
{
$offsetIndex = $i + 1; // allow for "Please make a selection"
$f01 = $rows[$i]->username;
$f02 = $rows[$i]->email;
print("if (pos_index == $offsetIndex) {populatefields (\"$f01\", \"$f02\");}"); 
}
print("}");
print("\n//--> </script>");

// end of JS script
```

It is not functioning as it should.  Is there anything which stands out as being incorrect from the formatting?

---

As noted in the comments below, the `populateFields()` function is a call to a built in function for a third party component in Joomla.  Here is the code:

```
function ff_SimpleSelect_init()
{
} // ff_SimpleSelect_init

function populateFields(f01, f02) 
{
ff_getElementByName('formField_01').value = f01; 
ff_getElementByName('formField_02').value = f02;  
}
```

The idea is that when the user selects a value from a drop down menu, then the other form entries updated with the username and email values associated with that user id.

Comment: Why are you generating JavaScript with PHP?

Comment: Why don't you use php templating? Manipulating scripts in strings like that is probably not a good idea.

Comment: That's a horrible way to output JavaScript from PHP. Also, we can't tell without knowing what `populateFields()` looks like, to begin with.

Comment: I know that this is pulled out of context and therefore does not make much sense.  I am trying to debug a bit of code that goes into a Joomla component that I am sure is outside the scope of this forum, so I am trying to hone in on the piece that is not functioning.  I will add the `populateFields()` info to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, but I see you used `<!--` at the first line. Do you mean to comment the following JS code?

But it's inside JS block and `<!--` is to comment the HTML code.

So you should use `/* ... */` to comment if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to eliminate that and it is still not functioning as designed.  I know it is a long shot trying to debug in this manner, but I appreciate that assistance.

Comment: Ovilia: HTML Comments in script tag is allowed for browsers not having javascript enabled as code will be rendered as text/html on page without html comments.

Comment: Good to know.  So, how about those backslashes.  Do those all seem correct?